# convert event aura:handler from Aura to LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, migration

I'm trying to convert below part of code from Aura to LWC:
**Aura Code**

```
<aura:handler name="myEvent" event="c:PPFields" action="{!c.handleEvent}" />
handleEvent(cmp, event, helper){
var wrapper = event.getParam("testWrapper");
        var object = wrapper.mapFieldApiObject;
        console.log(object);
}
```

**I tried as the following LWC**

````
dispatchMoveItems = (event) => {
        const passportFields = new CustomEvent('PPFields');
this.handleEvent(evnt);

        this.dispatchEvent(passportFields);
      }

handleEvent(event){
var wrapper = event.target.value;
        var object = wrapper.mapFieldApiObject;
        console.log(object);
}
```  So how could I convert above Aura handler to LWC and specifically event.getParam("testWrapper");
````

Answer (score 2):

You `event.target.value` is used mainly for `input` elements, if you pass custom data like with aura you need to use `event.detail`

```
dispatchMoveItems = (event) => {
        const passportFields = new CustomEvent('PPFields');
this.handleEvent(evnt);

        this.dispatchEvent(passportFields);
      }

handleEvent(event){
        var wrapper = event.detail;
        var object = wrapper.mapFieldApiObject;
        console.log(object);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,so event.detail.testWrapper, correct? and what do you think the way that I followed to convert is correct ?

Comment: ye, you can put in one line `event.detail.mapFieldApiObject`

Comment: and Does converting aura:handler in Aure to CustomEvent in LWC correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: if it answers your question please accept it

Comment: I found an issue there is two thing in Aura something is aura:register and aura:handler,and unfortunately, I'm waiting data team to fill the data to test the code, because I don't know where I supposed to put my code (in the file that contains aura:register or in the file that contains aura:handler). I mean by my code is dispatchMoveItems  function. so I don't want to accept the answer without testing.

Comment: `disptachEvent` you put where were you `registerEvent`. `handleEvent` you put where was your handle

Comment: here is the link from documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_events